# Swap words in VIM without using any third party plugins

Tags: linux, vim, swap

Assuming that I have a file containing only of characters and numbers (no special characters or punctuation marks), how can I swap two words that may or may not be right next to each other using VIM?

I tried the following (swap all occurrences of "Tom" with "Jerry") but it doesn't work for obvious reasons.

​:%s/Tom/Jerry/g​
:%s/Jerry/Tom/g

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3579112/382982) SO answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could use an intermediary variable like this

```
​:%s/Tom/XX9G235a65/g​ :%s/Jerry/Tom/g :%s/XX9G235a65/Jerry/g
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked exactly as I had wanted it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two variants (both using [`:help sub-replace-expression`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) and about equally cumbersome) that use a conditional operator and a Dictionary lookup, respectively:

```
:substitute/\<\(Tom\|Jerry\)\>/\=submatch(0) ==# 'Tom' ? 'Jerry' : 'Tom'/g
:substitute/\<\(Tom\|Jerry\)\>/\={'Tom':'Jerry', 'Jerry':'Tom'}[submatch(0)]/g
```

With this, you don't require an intermediate like in @MichaelDurrant's answer.